# How to define a sequence that takes every value of Z once and no other?

Tags: calculus

So I am supposed to define a sequence that takes every value of $$Z$$ once and no other value. I think I am supposed to do it in the form of $$a_n=n-1$$ for example. The problem I am having is not getting my head around how to make that into something that counts both positive and negative value and also counts 0.

Any help and hints are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here is a big [hint](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is, of course,
$$0,-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,...$$

The harder part is making an explicit formula for $a_n$.

How about (for $n=0,1,2,3,...)$:

$$a_n = \begin{cases} \frac n2 &  n \text{ even} \\ -\frac{n+1}2 & n \text{ odd} \end{cases}$$

And if piecewise definitions aren't allowed...

$$a_n = \frac{n}2\frac{(-1)^n + 1}2  - \frac{(n+1)}2 \frac{(-1)^{n+1} + 1}2$$

Comment: +1 You can write that closed formula more neatly as $$a_n=\frac{(2n+1)(-1)^n-1}4=\frac{(2n+1)\cos n\pi-1}4.$$

Answer (score 1):

You can define $a_n=\frac{n-1}{2}$, for $n$ odd, and $a_n=-\frac{n}{2}$ for $n$ even.

Answer (score 0):

$$
x_n = \left\{\begin{aligned}
& \frac{1}{2}n : n \in  \Bbb N_{even} \\
& -\frac{1}{2}(n-1) : n \in \Bbb N_{odd}
\end{aligned}
\right.$$